# Update issue when using STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

MySQL database has `Blogs` table  with columns `PostDate` and `ErrorMessage`. Both are of string data-type.

Now I need to apply validation if `PostDate` is `null`, blank, `0000-00-00` or 'unable to parse' then error message should be updated.

My query is as follows:-

```
UPDATE Blogs
SET ErrorMessage= 'Post date is Invalid.'
WHERE PostDate IS NULL OR PostDate = '' 
OR PostDate= '0000-00-00' OR  STR_TO_DATE(PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL;
```

Now this query fails if postdate contains any string like '16mar'  or 'Abc' etc. But I have heard `STR_TO_DATE` function will return `null` if it is unable to parse a date. 
This I tested using the `Select` statement also. Which is working fine.

```
SELECT *,STR_TO_DATE(PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM Blogs
WHERE PostDate IS NULL OR PostDate = '' 
OR PostDate= '0000-00-00' OR STR_TO_DATE(PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL;
```

I am unable to understand the problem in the update statement

update:--the error I am getting while updated is this :-
Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '16mar' for function str_to_date

Comment: change the data type of PostDate to the 'date' or 'timestamp'

Comment: share the error whatever you are getting.

Comment: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'IN VALID POST DATE' for function str_to_date

Comment: @SantoshJagtap PostDate will be supplied as string as it is coming from a URL which is monitored by 3rd party. we are dumping it into our DB and after validation we put it in mail table

Comment: @iGod set one record's date to 0000-01-00 and apply select query on it. and please share the result.

Comment: select works fine. date is set as 0000-01-00

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using friend`s help. since I was expecting the date to always come in special format (YYYY-DD-MM) so we used a regex.

```
UPDATE blogs
    SET ErrorMessage= 'Post date is invalid'
WHERE   (PostDate is null) 
    OR  (PostDate NOT REGEXP '^[1,2][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$');
```

This helped me to solve my problem, but question is still unanswered.